# Циклический код (кодирование/декодирование)

Tags: шифрование

1. Как найти порождающий многочлен?
2. Как вообще можно реализовать на языке программирования умножение и деление многочленов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как вообще можно реализовать на языке программирования умножение и деление многочленов?

Когда не знаете как, но умеете руками, воспользуйтесь алгоритмом из школы.

Есть класс Poly, у него есть коэффициенты при нужных степенях (ключи массива - степени, значения - коэффициенты).
Берете два таких класса.
При делении берете максимальную степень, вычитаете и ставите икс в этой степени с поделенным коэффициентом.
При умножении

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) for(j=0;j<m;j++)
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Деление_многочленов_столбиком